# Need help to make a loop and add variable for these php code

Tags: php, php-curl

I need help to create a loop with different value for AID with below coding format

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.max.com/core/v2/leads/getLeadData.do?AID=?????&api_secret=XG123CB&api_key=XGB3928?", CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST
=> "GET",   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",   

    ));

$response = curl_exec($curl); $err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; } else {   echo $response; }

   } ?>
```

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be? What have you tried to get to where you want to be? Do you have any clear information about what exactly is going on here?

Comment: i wast trying to get information from a curlop url site but i  can only do one a time when i hardcoded the AID. I want to  make the AID variable with array and loop it.

Comment: You only need to set the curlopts once, then you can just change the URL and re-run curl_exec().

Answer (score 0):

Set up your list of AIDS in the AID array,  set your CURLOPTS just once.  Change the url for each of your AIDS and then do something with the results as you like.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",
));

$AIDs = array(  ...  your list of AIDS);

foreach($AIDS as $id) {
   $url = sprintf("https://api.max.com/core/v2/leads/getLeadData.do?AID=%s&api_secret=XG123CB&api_key=XGB3928?",$id);
   curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   $response = curl_exec($curl); $err = curl_error($curl);

   if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
   } else {
      # do something this the response   
      echo $response;

      sleep(0);  # or sleep longer to not piss off the website you're harvesting 
   }
}

curl_close($curl);
```

}
   ?>

Now, you might need to toss 'sleep' in there to keep from abusing the website you're hitting too.